# How to fix a noisy jagged Segmentation using U-NET Architecture

Tags: machine-learning, image-segmentation, satellite-image

I'm trying to do a segmentation of Satellite images for identifying built and non-built areas using U-NET Architecture. The Model Architecture is as follows:

```
def get_unet(input_img, n_filters = 16, dropout = 0.1, batchnorm = True):
Function to define the UNET Model
# Contracting Path
c1 = conv2d_block(input_img, n_filters * 1, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)
p1 = Dropout(dropout)(p1)

c2 = conv2d_block(p1, n_filters * 2, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
p2 = Dropout(dropout)(p2)

c3 = conv2d_block(p2, n_filters * 4, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
p3 = Dropout(dropout)(p3)

c4 = conv2d_block(p3, n_filters * 8, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
p4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c4)
p4 = Dropout(dropout)(p4)

c5 = conv2d_block(p4, n_filters = n_filters * 16, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)

# Expansive Path
u6 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 8, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c5)
u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
u6 = Dropout(dropout)(u6)
c6 = conv2d_block(u6, n_filters * 8, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)

u7 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 4, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c6)
u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
u7 = Dropout(dropout)(u7)
c7 = conv2d_block(u7, n_filters * 4, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)

u8 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 2, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c7)
u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
u8 = Dropout(dropout)(u8)
c8 = conv2d_block(u8, n_filters * 2, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)

u9 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 1, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c8)
u9 = concatenate([u9, c1])
u9 = Dropout(dropout)(u9)
c9 = conv2d_block(u9, n_filters * 1, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)

outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
model = Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[outputs])
return model
```

However, my segmentation masks are noisy and pixelated, like this:

[U-NET mask for an airport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0yTg.png)

Also, When I tested my model with a sample image like this with solid colours it returned results like this.

[Tested with a solid colour using Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBE2n.png)

the U-Net masks in a jagged way thats not smooth. Is there any fix for this?

Thanks in Advance